# Speeding Up Recursive Evaluation

Tags: recursion

I have a recursive function for which I need the values for n=1 through about n=100,000,000 (or more). The function looks as follows, with output of the form ({x,y},a), and f, g, and h some functions.

```
coordinates[n_]:=coordinates[n]={{coordinates[n-1][[1]][[1]] +f[n, coordinates[n-1][[2]]], coordinates[n-1][[1]][[2]]+g[n, coordinates[n-1][[2]]]}, coordinates[n-1][[2]]+h[n]}
```

I then compute:

```
Table[coordinates[n][[All,1]], {n, 100,000,000}.
```

I can get up to a few million with about 4 hours of calculation time, but 100,000,000 causes my computer to crash and restart, stating "kernel panic" (I am not very familiar with programming unfortunately). Any advice about how to make such a table more easily calculated would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your definition of `coordinates[n_]` where is n actually being used in the calculation? Also, you say f and g are functions but they have parentheses rather than square brackets. In the Wolfram Language, arguments to functions should be surrounded by square brackets. Is it possible to post f and g, or are they very long?

Comment: What are the `coordinates[[1]][[1]]` supposed to refer to? Should they be something like `coordinates[n-1][[1,1]]`?

Comment: @MassDefect - yes, f and g are functions... they are rather long, and not really pertinent to the question, so I just gave the structure of the main function!

Comment: @Roman I was referring to coordinates[n-1][[1]][[1]]... is that the same as coordinates[n-1][[1,1]]?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I am attempting to plot the (x,y) coordinates in the first position of each output, and do need them all (or at lease a representative subset).

Comment: The same idea I showed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190410/38205) will work

Comment: @b3m2a1 Right, and that was super helpful, but I need ALL values, not just the last! That’s where I’m running into the time issue

Comment: @user413587 Please fix the syntax. Your code does not make sense.

Comment: Just updated the code

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need ALL values"? For what purpose? Hundreds of millions of values?

Comment: @Somos - I'm basically looking at visualizing the plot of all points (x,y) created at each step.

Comment: You do realize that there are an infinite number of points given by a recursion like yours. Do you want to look at ALL of the infinite points? Is this like zooming in a Mandelbrot fractal?

Comment: Well clearly that wouldn't be possible! I'm trying to see if structure emerges as n tends toward infinity.

Comment: @user413587 you can keep the huge list of values still using something like `NestList`. It's not the raw list size that's killing you (yet). *Recursion is expensive* memory-wise. Always keep that in mind.

Comment: @b3m2a1 that works much better. Still slow, but at least doesn't crash my machine! Is 75 secs per 1,000,000 reasonable?

Comment: 75s is a bit slower than I’d expect for what you’re doing. My guess is you could speed that up by a factor of say 10 or 100 by judicious application of clever Mathematica techniques.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @b3m2a1 does NestList still store the full list in active memory? I'm still having the kernel crash with a length of 100,000,000. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your recursion only depends on the previous value, but you are still trying to build up an awfully big table, which is possibly crushing your kernel. Use writing to the disk (hopefully an SSD) to capture the data. Simplified problem that hopefully captures the flow:

Simple recursion using memoization

```
fn[x_] := fn[x] = 1 + fn[x - 1];
fn[0] = 1;
```

Do it via memoization and capturing results in a table.

```
memBefore = MemoryInUse[];
res = Table[fn[i], {i, 10000}];
memAfter = MemoryInUse[];
memAfter - memBefore
(*  1813536 *)
```

Fast, but a memory hog for both the table and memoization.

Now don't memoize, and write each value to the hard drive that then creating a table. It slows the loop, but you'll not soak up any active memory.

```
memBefore = MemoryInUse[];
last = 1; Do[(current = 1 + last; current >>> "temp.csv"; last = current), {i, 10000}]
memAfter = MemoryInUse[];
memAfter - memBefore
(*  6264  *)
```

Comment: This should work - thank you!!

Comment: Is there any way to speed this process up? Even with a SSD, It's taking me about 7 secs per 1000 entries, which is way too slow? Thanks!

Comment: You could probably "bound" your way through the data, building up a table of 1,000,000 values and writing those to a disk, and then repeating. The disk write for each iteration is no doubt taking too long.

Comment: Great idea, thank you!